# C shell and mesa installation

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, tcsh

I am trying to install mesastar following these instructions:
[http://user.astro.wisc.edu/~townsend/static.php?ref=mesasdk](http://user.astro.wisc.edu/%7Etownsend/static.php?ref=mesasdk)

I do not have C Shell from prerequisites.

I have Linux mint and tried

```
sudo apt-get install csh
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

However, there is still that C Shell is missing.

In installation, there are steps:

Set the path to the SDK:

```
For the C shell: setenv MESASDK_ROOT ~/mesasdk
For the Bourne shell: export MESASDK_ROOT=~/mesasdk
```

Initialize the SDK (also checks compatibility):

```
For the C shell: source $MESASDK_ROOT/bin/mesasdk_init.csh
For the Bourne shell: source $MESASDK_ROOT/bin/mesasdk_init.sh
```

Should MESASDK_ROOT be replaced by my name (whoami)? Should I run just one option? Thank you very much.

Comment: `export MESASDK_ROOT=~/mesasdk` and `source $MESASDK_ROOT/bin/mesasdk_init.sh` are enough. The first command already sets it correctly.

Comment: Did the `apt-get` commands fail? if so, you may need to enable the `universe` repository in your software sources.